# Entity Framework Core: within the AppDbContact.OnConfiguring method, how do you add a user to the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Upon doing a release to my test environment, I want to be able to drop the database and recreate it including adding the existing SQL user.

Two questions immediately come to mind:

1. Am I correct in surmising that the place to do this is by overriding the `OnConfiguring` method within the `AppDbContext` class?
2. How within the `OnConfiguring` method do you grant the user permissions to the database? If it were in SQL script, it would be something like:

   ```
   USE [DatabaseName]
   GO
   IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'DatabaseUser')
       CREATE USER [DatabaseUser] FOR LOGIN [DatabaseUser]
   GO
   USE [DatabaseName]
   GO
   --ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [DatabaseUser] (gave a syntax error)
   EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner' 'DatabaseUser'
   GO
   ```

Comment: Have you tried to use the method Database.ExecuteSqlCommand ?